# How to check LED current

Tags: current, relay, attiny, lamp

I'd like to check if a lamp shines and if it's dead, a relay is supposed to switch.
I thought about using an ATtiny with a Hall sensor.

There are some sites that complain about the inconcurrency of the results of it.
I've got three lamps and I need to check each. They're UVC, so I can't use a photodiode to check for emitted light.

My idea was to use a Hall sensor for each supply cable and check the analog output with an ATtiny.

It would make use of 3 analog inputs and 4 digital outputs. Therefore the ATtiny84 would work.

If anyone has a better and cheaper idea, I'd be really grateful.

Edit: Thanks for your answers so far.

It looks like the project is going in another direction after all.

I will use UV-C LED strips for the whole project because they are much better suited for my purpose. However, I do not have the same current flow there as in an amalgam lamp. Is there a way to switch my relay in case of x failed LEDs?

Let's assume that the running meter of LED produces about 9.6W at 24VDC. I will use about two meters of LED strip. The 24V comes from a transformer. The LEDs will be switched off when not in use. I have to do the test during the active time. In itself no problem, because I can simply use one of the digital inputs on the ATtiny.

Now the question for me would be if the test with the Hall sensor is possible with the LEDs. The error relay should trip after about ten failed LEDs (I can measure the value for this by simply "leaving out" ten LEDs).

The whole thing should look relatively professional if possible, because I don't want to have a mess.

Comment: Hi, (a) Your question suggests you are assuming "current flow = lamp OK". What about any type of lamp problem where current is still drawn, but the lamp's output is so low that it is *effectively* unusable, despite the current flow? Is that possible for whatever lamps you have? What failure types are possible? In the same way as with a car engine, there are many other failure types that just "won't start", are you sure that you want to use the lamp's current as the criterion for whether it is "dead" or not? (b) Please edit the question to add details of the lamps and their power requirements.

Comment: You will be able to find UVC sensitive detectors. A low power UVC LED will act as a UVC sensitive photocell  and a much cheaper UVB or UVA LED may. | Hall sensors made for the job are entirely suitable for current measurement. As SamGibson says - be sure that current drain is an OK metric of performance. An Asian Arduino may be hardly  dearer than an ATtiny 84.

Comment: I edited my main post to update to the changes is my project.

Comment: As others have pointed out, if you plan to use your device for sterilization in a life-sustaining situation then you must verify that the amount of UVC irradiation is adequate, not just that the lamp(s) draw current. It is a very serious problem if you tell users that something has been sterilized if in fact it has not.

Comment: Hey Elliot, thanks for your concern :)
It's nothing life sustaining. Just a band people touch quite regularly and I want it to be mostly sterilized (Log1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution for a similar application for a remotely located lamp.

[image]

A standard transformer, with its rated secondary current equal to the lamp current, has been used as a current transformer.

It may be adapted for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Really there are two ways to go:

1. You can use a phototransistor/resistor that's physically aligned such that it modulates based on the brightness of the LED. It can be done but is obviously subject to the physical robustness of your circuit.
2. You can directly measure the current in the LED with [a low side current sense amplifier](https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/analogwire/posts/low-side-current-sensing-for-high-performance-cost-sensitive-applications). Since you'll want a current limiting resistor anyway, you can break it up in a way that you can pick up the current signal by measuring the voltage of that resistor and tuning your gain according to all the values. From there you can:

a. Get an analog reading if you want it: filter & put it into your micro's ADC.

b. Get a digital reading by cascading that with a comparator circuit with a threshold tuned the way you need/want it.